# slash quotes are disappearing after String.replace

Tags: java, string

This is just string replacement riddle but it has gone out of my hand.

```
String dataToBeReplaced = "#putReplacement|Expression#";
String toBeReplacedWith = "<a href=\"google.com\" link=\"The link\"></a>";
String toBeReplacedIn = "{Content:"#putReplacement|Expression#"}";

// What I am doing is
toBeReplacedIn.replaceAll(dataToBeReplaced.replace('|','.'),toBeReplacedWith);
//What I am getting in 'toBeReplacedIn'
//{Content:"<a href="google.com" link="The link"></a>"} 
**//In above output, see slashes are removed, this removal actually resulting in a string which is wrong Jason.**
```

Please suggest How can I substitute my 'toBeReplacedWith' **without losing any slashes in target String** 'toBeReplacedIn'.

Comment: You know why you add those slashes and what they mean right?. BTW you should try printing `toBeReplacedWith` and see whether it prints the slashes as well.

Comment: use replace('\\|','.')

Comment: Yeah I know. :) In actual scenerio, toBeReplacedWith is coming from database with slashes inside it. And with the replacement activity I shown I want it these slashes be preserved instead of getting omitted. They are part of data and and I am not doing typing job as   I have done while putting this question. Every value in above code is coming dynamically, slashes are the part of data like {"<a href=\"...\">"}. Now I will have to substitute it in other string.

Answer (score 1):

The [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method is behaving exactly as the javadoc says it should behave.

> "Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see [`Matcher.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-). Use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired."

The quoted text (above) even explains how to fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah I know.. In actual scenerio, toBeReplacedWith is coming from database with slashes inside it. And with the replacement activity I shown I want it these slashes be preserved instead of getting omitted. They are part of data and and I am not doing typing job as I have done while putting this question.

Comment: @assylias - But there are backslashes in `toBeReplacedWith` ... and those are the ones that are disappearing!!!

Comment: Yes toBeReplacedWith is coming from DB with slashes inside it. But then I want to preserve them, they are data, not mere escape symbols. Any ways I will be using this toBeReplacedWith to v=create Json which will be invalid  without these slashes.

Comment: So use `quoteReplacement` ... as the javadoc recommends!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for you, and it works. Here are the changes that you must do:

1. Use `\\\` for backslash literal.
2. Use  `Matcher.quoteReplacement` for treating `\` without a special meaning.

See below code:

```
    String dataToBeReplaced = "#putReplacement|Expression#";
    String toBeReplacedWith = "<a href=\\\"google.com\\\" link=\\\"The link\\\"></a>";
    String toBeReplacedIn = "{Content:\"#putReplacement|Expression#\"}";
    String x = toBeReplacedIn.replaceAll(dataToBeReplaced.replace('|','.'), Matcher.quoteReplacement(toBeReplacedWith));
    System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Thanks..:). In actual scenerio all the vars are coming from database. toBeReplacedWith is coming with slashes inside it. And with the replacement activity I shown I want it these slashes be preserved instead of getting omitted. They are part of data and and I am not doing typing job as I have done while putting this question.